# Javascript: operation with float and int

Tags: javascript, variables, int, operation

this is the entire code, I'm not be able to find the error:

```
var tmp = new Date();
var ora = tmp.getHours();
ora = parseInt(ora); 

var giorno = 98;
var delta = parseInt(23.45 * Math.sin((360 * (giorno - 81)) / 365));
delta = Math.round(delta);
delta = Math.abs(delta);
var col = 0;
col = -(ora - delta);
```

Why is 'col' undefined?

Comment: Why are you using parseInt for detla?  And 'Col' would be undefined since the variable is 'col'.

Comment: you are missing radix parameter for parseInt

Comment: I don't get `undefined`...http://jsfiddle.net/GteQH/

Comment: What makes you think you have an error? That is just a chunk of code. What do you expect it to do? What does it actually do? What is the difference?

Comment: the problem is that 'ora' is an INT, 'delta' too but in the end 'col' is undefined. I have to use it for others operations but they are 'undefined' due 'col'

Comment: `Math.sin` takes an argument in radians. Why are you multiplying by 360?

Comment: Why are you doing `-(ora-delta)` instead of `(delta-ora)`?

Comment: At the line you declare `col`, you assign 0 to it, but you overwrite the value at the very next line, and the zero is never seen.

Comment: Unary minus never returns `undefined`.

Comment: Normally one passes a string to `parseInt`. You pass a number. Did you mean `Math.round()`?

Answer (score 1):

`'Col' is undefined: why?` `Col` and `col` are two different names for Javascript Variables since JavaScript Variable names are case sensitive

Comment: That'd be a ReferenceError, not `undefined`.

Comment: yeah, sorry: why 'col' is undefined?

Comment: Error must be somewhere else then, because when I run your code I get the value `3` for `col`